# How to delete the last row with value within a table

Tags: excel, vba

What I want to do is to enable a user to delete the last row of data within a specific table. When the user does so, if they click the command button again, then the next row of data above is also deleted and so forth until this process stops at the header.

So in the image shown there are currently, 6 lines of data - the last row having numbers 160, 170 and 180 in the cells [P22, Q22 and R22 respectively]. When the user clicks the command button, these figures will be deleted. If the user then clicks the command button again then the next row of numbers above, being 130, 140 and 150 [P21, Q21 and R21 respectively] will be removed and so forth.

If say there are initially only 3 lines of data showing on the form,and the user clicks the command button, then the last figures in the row, 70, 80 and 90 [P19, Q19 and R19] would be deleted. If the command button is clicked again, then the figures in the row above, 40, 50 and 60 [P18, Q18 and R18] are deleted - process continues until stopping at the headers.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VMW8u.png)

Any help would be appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your "table" is an Excel table (and not just a range formatted to resemble a table), the code below should work.

My code assumes you have a table called `"Table1"` on a worksheet called `"Sheet1"`. Change as appropriate for you.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub DeleteLastRowInTable()
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1")
        If .ListRows.Count > 0 Then
            .DataBodyRange.Rows(.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

The `If` statement is meant to prevent errors when the table has no data (beneath its headers).

Comment: Should probably include the `CommandButton_Click` procedure given OP's original question as a fire event, but yeah. Kind of difficult when OP provided no code whatsoever

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the code. Yes should have mentioned that this is for an excel table. Have attempted to add in the CommandButton_Click procedure - unfortunately, when i run this i get an error - message says 'Run Time Error '9': Subscript out of Range'

Comment: @Ejike, that sounds like we're trying to access a sheet that doesn't exist. Change the name of the sheet and table in the code (if you haven't already done so). I used `"Sheet1"` and `"Table1"` as an example, but you should use whatever they're called in your workbook. Also, when you have the code open, press `F8` to run it line by line -- and you'll be able to see which exact line is throwing the error.

Comment: Hi Chillin. The worksheet I have is called 'Calculator' and the Table is 'Table1' - when i run the code the error is showing in line With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Calculator").ListObjects("Table1")

Comment: @Ejike, do you have the VBA code stored in the same workbook that the `"Calculator"` worksheet is in? Just to confirm, `With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Calculator").ListObjects("Table1")` (which is what you have) should be correct.

Comment: Yes the VBA code is stored in the same workbook that the Calculator worksheet is in. Unfortunately I am still getting the same error - will keep trying to work with the code you have provided

Comment: @Ejike, create a new variable and set a reference to the worksheet (just to see if you're able to) e.g. `Dim ws as worksheet: Set ws = Thisworkbook.worksheets("Calculator")`. Put this a separate procedure to run it in isolation. If that throws an error, there is something fundamentally wrong. You could also try referring to the sheet via its code name: https://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/excel-vba-sheet-names.htm. You could also try closing and re-opening Excel (and even restarting your PC).

Comment: Beyond that I'm not really sure what to suggest without seeing your workbook, sorry. Just to confirm, I did test the code on my side and it worked okay for me.

Comment: I've think I've worked out what I was doing wrong. The table i created was just a range of cells that I named - however, once I used 'Insert Table' to create a proper table, the error stopped occurring. The code deletes the entire row - what I want to do is clear the contents of the last row of the cells that have figures in the table - I ought to have made that more clear - thanks for all your help so far

Comment: @Ejike, try replacing this line `.DataBodyRange.Rows(.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count).EntireRow.Delete` with `.DataBodyRange.Rows(.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count).clearcontents` -- or you can also try replacing with  `.DataBodyRange.Rows(.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count).delete xlShiftUp`. The first one will delete the contents of the last row (make it empty) but preserve formatting, etc -- and the second one will only delete the last cells within the table (but not the entire row), and any cells beneath the deleted cells will be moved up. Use whichever one gives you required outcome.

Comment: Hi Chillin - thank you very much for the code. I have actually managed to sort this out using a series of if-else statements - using a total for each row and if total is greater than 0 - then code blanks out the row and this moves up the table until the headers - which works perfectly. However, I really appreciate all he help that you provided